# mail() in lampp doesn't work

Tags: apache, email, smtp, php

I'm trting to send a simple mail script in PHP. It doesn't work and I have no error in mail log or error log.

Here's my php.ini config

```
SMTP = relais.videotron.ca
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = xxxx@xxxx.com (Of cours it's my ISP email there :D)
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t
```

and my simple mail() test

```
mail("xxxx@xxxx.com","test","test");
```

Nothing's work. What could it be?

Comment: Is sendmail on it's own working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in PHP `mail` command doesn't allow you to authenticate to an SMTP server. Your ISP SMTP server requires authentication and so is refusing the connection.

The [info provided by your ISP](http://support.videotron.com/residential/internet/installation/server-address) confirms this;

> SMTP server is accessible from an external network by using clear text
>   authentication using your code "VL" or alias for your mail Example:
>   customer@videotron.ca

Your options are either use an SMTP server that allows anonymous connections or (as Eamorr says) use a mailer class.

Comment: That's what i've tought too... Well I test it when it'll be online on a true server. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's a common problem. There a plenty of free SMTP servers you can install on your machine if you need - http://www.google.co.uk/?q=free+smtp+server

Answer (score 0):

I use SwiftMailer:

```
require_once('../lib/swiftMailer/lib/swift_required.php');
...
function sendEmail(){
  //Sendmail
  $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

  //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

  $body="Dear $fname,\n\nYour job application was successful. \n\nYours,\n\nEamorr\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";


  //Create a message
  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject goes here')
    ->setFrom(array($email => "no-reply@yourdomain.com"))
    ->setTo(array($email => "$fname $lname"))
    ->setBody($body);

  //Send the message
  $result = $mailer->send($message);
}
```

You can send both plaintext and html email with ease.